# Login with Twitter on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitterkit

I have a problem with twitter login on iOS. If the user has account set in Settings application, I get the following error:

> [TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "User's system account
>   credentials are invalid.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=7
>   "The system account credentials are no longer valid and will need to
>   be updated in the Settings app." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   system account credentials are no longer valid and will need to be
>   updated in the Settings app., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The user
>   has been prompted to visit the Settings app.}

And the credentials are valid, I double check that.
If there are no account in Settings app, my login goes as expected. 
The method I call is:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion {(session, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: You can use FHSTwitterEngine for twitter login

Comment: @Jecky thanks. I solved it by using other method.

Comment: @Nemanja could you tell us what method you used?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following method should also work.

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(withCompletion: {(session: TWTRSession, error: Error) -> Void in
    if session {
        print("@\(session.userName()) logged in! (\(session.userID()))")
    }
    else {
        print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```

> It takes the account credentials from the Settings Twitter app.

More to look into:
- AppDelegate.m

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
    //Twitter
    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(with: kTwitterConsumerKey, consumerSecret: kTwitterConsumerSecret)
    Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])
    return true
}
```

- Info.plist

[image]

Comment: This doesn't not work for me, it is the same like in my question.

Comment: Yes it seem to be same, but it works well with the sdk's which are installed using 'fabric'. How you have added the twitter frameworks?

Comment: Yes, I have added twitterkit and fabric kit using pods and set twitter settings, tested with plist and programatically.

Comment: I have updated my answer, with some addition of code, kindly check, and also tell me the version of iOS on which you are testing this?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I did. I am testing on iOS 10. So, my steps are: 1) remove account from settings. 2) twitter offers me login in webview and I am logged in. 3) I logout in my app and try to login again. 4) I get the popup saying I don't have valid credentials and that I should change those in settings. Even if I change those, still doesn't work. The method in my second response works as expected. I still haven't tried what Anthony wrote in his response.

Comment: have you added the line     [[Twitter sharedInstance] logOut]; when you actually do logout.

Comment: Hm, I haven't do that, maybe that is the case. But without adding logout, method in my other response works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn { session, error in
        if (session != nil)
        {
            print("signed in as \(session!.userName)");
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
            let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET",
                url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
                parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"],
                error: nil)
            client.sendTwitterRequest(request)
            { response, data, connectionError in
                print(response)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
        }
    }
```

this helps me in **swift3**

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by using method:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithMethods(TWTRLoginMethod.WebBased, completion: {(session, error) -> Void in
```

But still think other method should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like using the below code, Might be it Help

```
 TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self, completion: { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
          }
   }
```